# if else microwave oven exam

Tags: php, if-statement

Please help me in answering this question below. I don't understand what the problem is stating:

> A microwave oven manufacturer recommends that when heating two items, add 50% to the heating time, and when heating three items double the heating time. Heating more than three items at once is not recommended.
>
> Write a program that accepts the number of items and the single-item heating time. The program then writes out the recommended heating time.
>
> Hint: do this with four successive single-branch if statements each of which tests for one of the four cases: 1 item, 2 items, 3 items, more than three items.

Comment: Maybe we shouldn't be doing people's compsci 101 homework?

Comment: I always set my microwave to 2:22, whatever the number of items is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd say a chain of `if` statements is very much the wrong way to go. I would do something along these lines:

```
// $item_count = number of items
// $single_time = time for one item
if( $item_count > 3) echo "It is not recommended to heat more than three items.";
else echo "Time: ".($single_time*(0.5+0.5*$item_count))." seconds";
```

Basically, I take the three valid cases and turn them into a formula:

> `$item_count = 1` leads to `0.5+0.5*1 = 1`: normal time
>   `$item_count = 2` leads to `0.5+0.5*2 = 1.5` = 50% extra
>   `$item_count = 3` leads to `0.5+0.5*3 = 2` = double time

Comment: If the assignment says to use `if` statements, it probably wants `if` statements. :-)

Comment: My first assignment told me to use Dreamweaver. I threw it out the window and used Notepad, scoring best in the class. Personally, I think classes should teach you how to do things right the first time, as it can be very hard to "unlearn" cheap habits.

Comment: Personally, I think so too. However, my experience tells me that when an instructor says to do something a certain way and you don't, you usually don't get a passing grade. (Of course, there are exceptions to every rule, but...)

Comment: If an instructor punishes you for writing better code, I would not take their class. In fact, I'd pursue the relevant paths to get them fired.

Comment: What planet are you from? That's not the way that the real world works, either in the US (where I'm located) or the UK (where you are). Anyway, this is off-topic. The question asked how to do this according to the description they posted, and the description says `if statements`. Perhaps there's some basic logic being taught here that the poster obviously doesn't grasp yet, and bypassing it because you feel superior doesn't help them learn those basics.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check how many items are being entered to the microwave and accept a heating time. If there is one item use the entered heating time, if there are two items add 50% and if there are three then double it. You should also stop there being more than three items.

You may wish to do something like this:

```
$size = 3; // Any number
$time = 60;

// No need to check for one input because it doesn't affect time
// Check if two inputs
if ($size == 2) {
    $time += ($time * 0.5);
}
// I'll leave three and more than three inputs to you
echo $time;
```

You may alternatively wish to use a case statement and use default for 0 or more than 3 items :)

```
$size = 3; // Any number
switch ($size) {
    case 1:
     // Do something
    break;
    // etc
    default:
}
```

If you're confused about how to read input, you should look in to the $_GET and $_POST variables if you're using HTML input forms.

Comment: How does "the number of items" translate to "an array of items"?